# Prolog failure driven loop exam answer?

Tags: prolog

Below are two rules from a Prolog database:

```
 rule1 :-a, b, c, fail, d.

 rule1 :-e.
```

**(i)** What is the role of ‘fail’?

**(ii)** Under what circumstances will subgoal `d` be executed?

**(iii)** Under what circumstances will subgoal `e` be executed?

I understand  most of the questions for this but **(ii)** I cannot see when `d` would be executed. Do you?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**(i)** The `fail/0` predicate is provided by Prolog. When it is called, it causes the failure of the rule.

I went ahead and defined the rules `a` to `e` so you can understand:

This is my program:

```
rule1 :-a, b, c, fail, d.

rule1 :-e.

a:-write('a').
b:-write('b').
c:-write('c').
d:-write('d').
e:-write('e').
```

And when I execute `rule1.` I get:

```
3 ?- rule1.
abce
true.
```

So, this is what this program does:

> Writes 'a', 'b' ,'c', then the first 'rule1' fails (hence 'd' isn't written) and then the program writes 'e' and finishes.

**(ii)** As you can  see, the rule `d` is never executed with the rules as they are, because the rule you have defined fails before it can execute the sub goal `d`. In order to execute it, you will have to define it otherwise. A simple example would be

```
rule1 :-a, b, c, d, fail.
```

But this would change the core of your program.

**(iii)** With the program as it is, the rule `e` is executed when you run the query `rule1.`

Comment: I think it's also good to note that the query `rule1` only has one successful path, through to the writing of `e`. It succeeds once and has no place to backtrack to. So just one solution, the one you've shown.